# Backing up and restoring Vagrant Boxes

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I had a Vagrant box called **dev** and backed up `Vagrantfile` and `~/.vagrant.d/boxes/dev` before reinstalling my OS

And then reinstalled my OS. After that installed Vagrant and copied `dev` folder to `~/.vagrant.d/boxes` folder again. When I up the vagrant box and ssh into it, it's not the same box. It's just a fresh copy of CentOS.

Can you tell me which files also I need to backup?

Content of `dev` folder

`.
└── 0
    └── virtualbox
        ├── Vagrantfile
        ├── box.ovf
        ├── metadata.json
        ├── packer-virtualbox-iso-1456527368-disk1.vmdk`

Comment: Based on the information you provided, this should be enough. Unless you are hiding (consciously or unconsciously) more information about your past configuration.

Comment: your box is not your VM. on your new laptop, you have initialized a new dev VM from your box (which is a bare OS) if you want to keep the same VM you need to copy the files from your dev (VM not box) folder